# SQL READING THE COLUMN VALUES?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

0.0.0.1 saved in sql table column as 10001.
MY data base contains values as such above mentioned i wanted to sort it based on the values but if I sort is as it is it will give me wrong order so i need tp convert it to the above mentioned format(10001). i.e. Remove the dots(.)

Thank you.

Comment: How does 0.0.0.1 become 10001? Where is the leading 1 magicked from

Comment: Please post your schema and sample data

Comment: You have both `mysql` and `oracle` tagged. Those are two different RDBMS products. Please remove the one you aren't using.

Answer (score 0):

(I guess you're actually using Oracle as a database, regarding the tool - Oracle SQL Developer - you've also tagged, which means that MySQL tag should be removed).

---

To me, it looks as if you'd want to **a)** remove dots, **b)** change datatype to number (so that it is correctly sorted):

```
order by to_number(replace(col, '.', ''))
```

It presumes that only characters allowed are digits and dots. If there's a value like 'A.0.0.1', it'll - of course - fail, as you can't convert letter A to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing  the period '.' Character to begin with? If it's not needed you can remove it.

If you want to remove all non-alphanumeric characters you could use a regular expresion.

```
create table t (nm varchar2(20));

insert into t values ('.0.0.0.1');
insert into t values ('10.0.1.1.0');
commit;
select * from t;

NM
.0.0.0.1
10.0.1.1.0


update t 
set    nm = regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(nm, '[^A-Z0-9 ]', ''),
         ' {2,}', ' '
       );

select * from t;

NM
0001
100110
```

Comment: i need the column values in the same format i cannot change anything is their any work around?

Comment: Can we some how use cast function to get the required ouput?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the translate command with a SELECT and the data will not be charged  in the table.

See below

```
create table t (nm varchar2(20));

insert into t values ('.0.0.0.1');
insert into t values ('10.0.1.1.0');
commit;


SELECT translate(nm, '*.','*') from t

TRANSLATE(NM,'*.','*')
0001
100110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name)
FROM Table_name
ORDER BY 
TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_name, '\d+',1,2)),
TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_name,'\d+',1,3)) NULLS FIRST,
TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column_name,'\d+',1,4)) NULLS FIRST;
```

Comment: Hi found a way to sort them as versions/releases keeping the same formate.